# Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

This isn't duplicate. I have tried every solution available online but still there is error.
I understand ForEach require every item having unique id. So I ensured the struct object I am iterating confirm to identifiable protocol and id = UUID().
Each item going to ForEach loop is unique by id. The ids are as follows:

6AE07B12-4059-4926-8367-ED3E0D27668F

6FD3DCE6-B2D6-4807-9F7D-1D8671103520

044961D5-82A2-4771-8A13-7D6AE9B6A729

00F15D37-C7F3-4356-ACEF-BE16C99AF672

86F08922-BC16-475B-938D-8ADC9440B549

1AE7557C-0225-4C1A-A688-39DE8F521EB9

79532ED5-B2F5-4C1E-A29E-0760E23F9C1B

C5BB142F-9EE2-46BD-AC6B-84504A2E7890

0342C58B-244E-4330-B4E1-06AA3255BC95

E024829A-65A8-450A-B8D4-49DCF98BED53

7132555E-E04E-490A-BEA8-E6E662806600

FB899576-8697-4682-A0A3-8E37D7529AF3

8AE365D6-0340-4A9A-B832-90526A82382F

B3553352-84AA-44FC-8F2E-72E77EF34DAC

8D9CF0E4-A001-4973-9AEE-AE0F98B9C8D8

The above are unique ids of each item

```
struct TweetList: View {
    var tweetList: [Tweet]
    var body: some View {
        
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(tweetList.sorted(by: { (t1, t2) -> Bool in
                    t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
                }),id: \.self) { (tweet)  in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TweetView(tweet: tweet)) {
                        
                        Text("\(tweet.text)")
                                .padding()
                             
                    }
                   
                }
            }
        
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Tweets"))
    }
}
```

Tweet is

```
struct Tweet: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var userName: String
    var createdAt: Date
}
```

I am unable to identify what is giving trouble here even the ids are completely unique.
please tell the way to fix this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide minimal standalone reproducible example to debug.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, tested on Xcode 12.3 using iOS 14.3.

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Probably the issue is in other code.

Comment: facing the same issue, started today. very weird.. xcode 12.3, ios 14.1

Comment: Since your model is already `Identifiable`, then try deleting the `id` argument in your `ForEach`, otherwise SwiftUI is using the `Hash` value of the struct to create another `id`, also please add the error message to we can see that Xcode says.

Comment: This issue happened to me I notice is only happened  if array have one item
I did remove it all before request other item from API but same crash happened 
I notice also if I change lazyvstkck to Stack it won't crash but it will duplicate the item 
very weird